# How can I protect all possible function names?

Tags: functions

It is possible to protect all possible function names?

All functions have `Attributes`, e.g.

```
Attributes[Plus]
```

will give

```
{Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}
```

I can change a function's attributes by running something like this

```
Attributes[Plus]={"Protected"};
```

but, can I make all possible functions `Protected`?

Comment: ``Protect["*`*"]``? I am not sure how is ``Attributes[Plus]={"Protected"};`` related to the question. p.s. the most important question is: but why?

Comment: @Kuba ```Protect["*`*"]``` may break internal things. ```Protect["Global`*"]``` would be a bit safer.

Comment: @Shadowray who said we want to be safe here? :)

Comment: Whether all or just ``Global` ``, one should be clear whether it's all symbols or just symbols that are "function names" that are to be protected.

Comment: @Kuba If we play "shortest code to crash a fresh kernel" game, then running```Protect["*`*"]``` after `Quit[]` is a really good candidate to win :)

Comment: @Shadowray to be clear, for me the question is not clear and weird, making it only slightly less weird by adding Global` does not make much sense :)

Comment: @Shadowray, playing the game, might `InitializationValue[$Initialization]=Protect["*`*"]` do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify things:

> All functions have Attributes [...]

No, try  `foo[x_] := x; Attributes @ foo`

> I can change a function's attributes [...]

Attributes are not specified by string names but symbols. It should be `Protected` not `"Protected"`.

> It is possible to protect all possible function names?

**Depends** what do you really want and what do you think a function is.

You could do `` Protect["*`*"] `` to protect all symbols

**But** maybe you don't want to corrupt e.g. `` System` `` context. Then you could go with `` Protect["`*"] `` to protect current (usually `` Global` ``) context. What about contexts of your packages that are loaded, are they supposed to be immune? Which contexts should be affected?

**But** you don't want to protect variables, righ? (`x = 1;`), then you may need to select those symbols which have associated `DownValues`.

**Unless** that is not enough to decide what is a function: `foo = Function[x, x^2]`...

**Theoretically** there could be a symbol that has `Locked` attribute without `Protected`. At least then the answer is clear, you can't.